# form validation question

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I have a question about form validation in CodeIgniter:

```
<? form_open('user/check_login' ?>
  <fieldset id="login_fields">
     <label for="login">Login</label>
          <input name="login" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" />
     <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" />
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

As the you can see above, the form is submitted to check_login method in user controller.

After a certain number of unsuccessful login attempts, I would include another input field (captcha) in the form. For example

```
<? if ($attempts > 3) { ?>
<label for="captcha">captcha</label>
          <input name="captcha" type="text" class="textfield" id="captcha" />
<? } ?>
```

But the problem is that when the extra field is added, and the form is submitted then, how the check_login method will know that this time captcha field was added in the form, and that can not be left blank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isset( $_POST['captcha'] )

or

$this->input->post('captcha') not equals to FALSE

if any of this conditions are meet, the add the rule to the form_validation.

Answer (score 1):

You're either need to use the [CI session](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) library or the [PHP $_SESSION array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Personally, I would use flash_data in the session lib.

```
$this->load->library('session');
$attempts = $this->session->flashdata('fails');
if(!is_numeric($attempts)) $attempts = 0;
else $attempts++;
$this->session->set_flashdata('fails', $attempts);
```

At that point, you can just pass $attempts to your view and you should be good.